# Two cin / cout statements being combined into one

Tags: c++, cin, cout

I've just started trying to get into C++ coming from C and it's similar enough to be easy to pick up but subtly different in slightly infuriating ways (I miss you malloc). Regardless, my problem here is that I'm trying my hand at structs in C++ and the enterBookInformation function is called twice, once for each book. However, on the second calling of the function, the first two cin / cout statements for title and author combine and turn into

```
Enter Title of Book: Enter Author of Book:
```

The first calling of the function works just fine though. I thought it might have something to do with maybe buffer flushing (?) just as my experience in C and the behavior of this bug is, but I wouldn't have a definitive clue and can't find anything online relating to my question. Here's my code:

```
//struct_example.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <iomanip>
using std::setw;

#include <cstring>

struct books_t enterBookInformation(struct books_t book, unsigned short counter);
void printBooks(struct books_t book1, struct books_t book2);

struct books_t {
    char title[50];
    char author[50];
    int year;
};

int main(void) 
{
    struct books_t book1;
    struct books_t book2;
    book1 = enterBookInformation(book1, 1);
    book2 = enterBookInformation(book2, 2);
    printBooks(book1, book2);
}

struct books_t enterBookInformation(struct books_t book, unsigned short counter)
{
    char title[50], author[50];
    int year;
    std::cout << "Enter Title of Book " << counter << ": ";
    std::cin.getline(title, sizeof(title));
    std::cout << "Enter Author of Book " << counter << ": ";
    std::cin.getline(author, sizeof(author));
    std::cout << "Enter the Year of Publication " << counter << ": "; 
    std::cin >> year;
    strcpy(book.title, title);
    strcpy(book.author, author);
    book.year = year;
    return book;
}

void printBooks(struct books_t book1, struct books_t book2)
{
    std::cout << setw(15) << "Book 1 Title: " << setw(25) << book1.title << endl;
    std::cout << setw(15) << "Book 1 Author: " << setw(25) << book1.author << endl;
    std::cout << setw(15) << "Book 1 Year: " << setw(25) << book1.year << endl;
    std::cout << setw(15) << "Book 2 Title: " << setw(25) << book2.title << endl;
    std::cout << setw(15) << "Book 2 Author: " << setw(25) << book2.author << endl;
    std::cout << setw(15) << "Book 2 Year: " << setw(25) << book2.year << endl;
}
```

The output for me trying to enter Othello and Moby Dick as books looks like this right now:

```
./struct_example 
Enter Title of Book 1: Othello
Enter Author of Book 1: William Shakespeare
Enter the Year of Publication 1: 1603
Enter Title of Book 2: Enter Author of Book 2: Herman Melville
Enter the Year of Publication 2: 1851
 Book 1 Title:                   Othello
Book 1 Author:       William Shakespeare
  Book 1 Year:                      1603
 Book 2 Title:                          
Book 2 Author:           Herman Melville
  Book 2 Year:                      1851
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521884/stdgetline-reads-wrong-data-after-reading-formatted-input-from-stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing calls to `getline()` with `cin >>`.  The latter doesn't consume trailing linefeeds.

You could replace

```
std::cin >> year;
```

with

```
{
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s)
    year = std::stoi(s);
}
```

Do `#include <string>` to make the above work.

There are other ways you could deal with it, too.  The point is that you need to consume the trailing linefeed.

Comment: Thanks, this did end up working. It kept giving me an error that std has no member stoi, but after some research I found that including -std=c++11 in the compile statement linked libraries that g++ doesn't include automatically. Thanks for the help again